# Give example where an outer measure is strictly less than the set function from which it is defined.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $K $ be a class of subsets of $X $ where for every subset $A $ of $X $ there is a sequence $\{E _n \}  $ of sets  in $K $ such that $A \subset \bigcup _{n=1 }^{\infty } E _n $.

Let $\lambda$ be a extended-real valued, nonnegative  set function, with $\lambda ( \emptyset )=0$

Define $$\mu(E)= \inf \left\{\sum _{n=1 } ^{\infty } \lambda(E _n): E _n \in K, A \subset \bigcup _{n=1 }^{\infty } E _n \right\}$$

Show that if $E \in K $ then $\mu(E) \le \lambda (E) $  and give an example of where strict inequality holds.

I think that if $E \in K $ , then $ \lambda (E ) $ is in the set from which we take infinum of in the definition of $ \mu $ and thus $\mu (E) \le \lambda (E) $.

But how can you give an example of a set function $\lambda $ where strict inequality holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $X = \mathbb R$, $K = \{[a,b] : a,b \in \mathbb R\}$, $\lambda([a,b]) = (b-a)^2$.

$\lambda([0,2]) = 4$.

$[0,2] \subset [0,1] \cup [1,2]$ implies $\mu([0,2]) \le \lambda([0,1]) + \lambda([1,2]) = 2$.